# how to use the return attribute within an azure function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

**Is it possible to return the response directly into a storage account by specifying connection info in the attribute?**

In the following example I believe that this is similar to what I am looking for:

`[return: EventHub("results", Connection = "EhConnectionString")]`

Full context:

```
    [FunctionName("DequeAndForwardOn")]
    [return: EventHub("results", Connection = "EhConnectionString")]
    public static string Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testqueue", Connection = "SbConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        EventHubOutput message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventHubOutput>(myQueueItem);
        message.ProcessedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        return json;
    }
```

My expectation is for something like this:

```
    [return: StorageAccount("myStorageAccount/{myBlobContainer}", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Functions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output) for Blob bindings explains how to do this. It is slightly different from the EventHub binding.

```
[FunctionName("ResizeImage")]
    public static void Run(
    [BlobTrigger("sample-images/{name}")] Stream image,
    [Blob("sample-images-sm/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageSmall, //output blob
    [Blob("sample-images-md/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageMedium)
    {
         //your code here
    }
```

Comment: what happens if we specify `FileAccess.Read`? i understand that with `FileAccess.Write` when we mutate `Stream imageSmall`, its contents will be written to `sample-images-sm/{name}` at the end of the function execution?

Comment: You would use ```FileAccess.Read``` if you want to use changes to your blob storage as a trigger for the function. Since you are looking to output data to the storage account, you need to request ```FileAccess.Write``` permission.